# CPP, Variables don't go out of scope

Tags: c++, memory, scope, destructor

in all my other experiments i have done, my variables go out of scope as intended, but when i put variables in the main method, they don't go out of scope or that's what it seems like because the destructor never gets called:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define PRINT(s) cout << s
#define PRINTLN(s) PRINT(s) << endl

class Animal
{
public:
    string name;
    int legs;

    Animal(string name, int legs) {
        this->name = name;
        this->legs = legs;
    }

    ~Animal(){
        PRINTLN("deleting");
    }
    static Animal createAnimal() {
        PRINTLN("creating");
        return Animal("animal", 4);
    }
};

int main() {
    PRINTLN("start");
    Animal a = Animal::createAnimal();//or Animal a("hello", 5);
    PRINTLN("end running method");

    PRINTLN("end");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    //should print out "deleting" here 
    //because of a going out of scope
}
```

Comment: It should print deleting after the return. Run your program from the command line to see that. or press ctrl-f5 to run without debugging on Visual Studio.

Comment: Where is the `include`s?

Comment: That's the problem, it's not printing delete at all

Comment: I assume you are on Visual Studio and after the return windows closed the window so fast you did not see the result. That is why I gave you 2 methods to get around that.

Comment: #include <iostream> and  #include <string>

Comment: When I run your code it prints "deleting" as expected.

Comment: Ohh, it is printing after it pauses and immediately exits...thank you

Comment: You will see it if you run your program in a command line window (that doesn't close right after execution)

Comment: Ok, yea if i run it in normal cmd, it shows up, thank you everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point in your code where you have the comment

```
//should print out "deleting" here 
//because of a going out of scope
```

"a" *isn't* out of scope.  It will go out of scope as the application terminates.  Other similar questions  ([Are destructors run when calling exit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7054685/2381157)) discuss what you can expect when the application terminates.