# How to solve RUN_ERROR even though it compiles normally?

Tags: c++

I am currently writing a script about finding the nearest duplicate from a user entered size array.
The array must be between 1 and 10^5 and its value has to be between 1 and 10^5 also.
It compiles normally on my computer but whenever I submit it, it returns a run_error.

Here's what I wrote.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void input (int *);
int main(){
    int n;
    input (&n);
    int a[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if (scanf("%d",&a[i])!=1) 
            return 0;
        if ((a[i]>100000)||(a[i]<1))
            return 0;

        }

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if (a[abs(a[i])]>=0){
            a[abs(a[i])]=-a[abs(a[i])];
        } else {
            printf("%d",abs(a[i]));
            return 0;
        }
    } 
    return 0; 
}

void input(int *x){
    if (scanf("%d",x)!=1)
        exit(0);
    if ((*x>100000)||(*x<1))
        exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `int a[n];` potentially allocates a very large amount of memory on the stack. Make it a global or use malloc.

Comment: `a[abs(a[i])]` this will be out of bounds when `a[i] = 100000`

Comment: @RetiredNinja I wouldn't call 100,000 a large amount of memory. Stack should be fine.

Comment: @AvinKavish Not all stacks are created equal. I'd play it safe.

Comment: Variable length arrays are not part of standard C++. Some compilers support VLAs as an extension, but you really shouldn't use them. Use a `std::vector` when you need a dynamic array and `std::array` when you need a fixed size one.

Comment: The usage of `int a[n]` is not even valid C++.    Unfortunately, it is a non-standard extension that some C++ compilers support.   If it is supported, the array sizes possible are significantly smaller than is possible using `malloc()`, since it uses "stack" memory - most modern operating systems limit processes to a small quota of stack.

Answer (score 0):

This program is logically incorrect. There is no connection between the size of the array defined in `n` and the limit of the allowed elements.

Since you have allowed `a[i]>100000` to go up to 10^5 with no regards to the size of the array defined by `a[n]`, the following access will attempt to access outside the bounds of the array, a[abs(a[i])] for any `a[i] > n`.

Also, you can pass by reference for syntactical simplicity

```
input(n);

void input(int &x){
    if (scanf("%d",&x)!=1)
        exit(0);
    if (x>100000 ||x<1)
        exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are writing in C, please tag this question as C question, and not as C++ one. `scanf` & `printf` are C functions, as much as your includes `stdio.h` & `stdlib.h` & `math.h`. In c++ you have the include `iostream`, and in this case it's all you really need.

The second problem here is the way you handle the input validation when it wrong. `exit` is very dangerous way, and very not recommended. If you want to throw exception use `throw` method (Read about the difference between the two: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56406586/8038186). But, in this case I don't understand why do you need to throw exception at all. you can simply finish the program in more gentle way. Consider the following flow:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Num is moved by reference and not by pointer
bool input(int &num) { // return true if the input is good, otherwise return false.
    cout << "Please enter number: " << endl; // Tell the user that he should enter a number.
    cin << num;
    bool is_valid = num >= 1 && num <= 1e5; // 1e5 = 100000
    if (!is_valid) cout << "Invalid input." << endl;
    return is_valid;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    if (!input(n)) {
        return 0;
    }
    int a[n];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n && input(a[i]); i++);
    if (i < n) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // The following if is useless, the validation make sure already that all of the numbers are legal.
        //if (a[a[i]] >= 0) { // You don't need abs(a[i]), a[i] > 1
        if (a[i] < n)
            a[a[i]] = -a[a[i]];
        else cout << "Consider what do you want to do" << endl;
        /*} else {
            printf("%d", a[i]);
            return 0; 
        }*/
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Read about the difference between reference and pointer: [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)