# std::function from dlsym results in segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linux, dynamic-linking, std-function, dlsym

I want to dynamically link a shared library and assign a function from it to a `std::function`. Here is the code:

**function.cpp:**

```
#include <array>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

double function(std::array<double, 1> arg)
{
    return arg[0] * 2;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>
#include <functional>

#ifdef __linux__
#include <dlfcn.h>
#endif

int main()
{
void *handle;
double (*function)(std::array<double, 1>);
char *error;

handle = dlopen("/home/oleg/MyProjects/shared_library_test/libFunction.so", RTLD_LAZY);
if (!handle) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

dlerror();
*(void **) (&function) = dlsym(handle, "function");

if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

std::cout << "Native function output: " << function(std::array<double, 1>{ 3.0 }) << std::endl;
dlclose(handle);

std::function<double(std::array<double, 1>)> std_function(*function);
std::cout << "std::function output: " <<  std_function(std::array<double, 1>{ 3.0 }) << std::endl;

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Build shared library:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++17 -shared -o libFunction.so -fPIC function.cpp
```

Build main:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++17 main.cpp -ldl
```

Running the program leads to the following output:

```
Native function output: 6
Segmentation fault
```

So, as you can see, I successfully compile the library and load it in my main program. However, assigning the function pointer to `std::function` doesn't work.

Please, help!

Comment: What does the `gdb` debugger tells about that crash ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch sorry, don't know how to use gdb, I've been working only in IDEs. Btw I'll try to do something with it and tell what it says if it's still actual :)

Comment: what is `std_function`?

Comment: @keith a std::function instance, obviously.

Comment: When coding in C++, you need to learn how to use `gdb`. If you feel that using the debugger thru some IDE is easier, do it that way. I recommend taking several hours to learn how to use `gdb` on the command line

Comment: @Oleg Yablokov, no it's not obvious, you should really write `std::function`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You better do conversion in C++ style:

```
using function_ptr = double (*)(std::array<double, 1>);
function_ptr function = reinterpret_cast<function_ptr>( dlsym(handle, "function") );
```

But the culprit is that you cannot call this function directly or indirectly through `std::function` wrapper after you close shared library:

```
dlclose(handle);
// function cannot be used anymore
```

note it can be better to use RAII for this:

```
std::unique_ptr<void *,int(void*)> handle( dlopen("/home/oleg/MyProjects/shared_library_test/libFunction.so", RTLD_LAZY), dlclose );
```

then you do not need to call `dlclose()` manually

Note: it is a bad idea to call exit from `main()` in C++, use `return` instead, details can be found here [Will exit() or an exception prevent an end-of-scope destructor from being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668075/will-exit-or-an-exception-prevent-an-end-of-scope-destructor-from-being-called)

Comment: There was a similar (deleted though) answer about it. It doesn't solve the problem, I still get Segmentation fault when trying to use std::function

Comment: Yay, it helped! Thank you :)

Comment: The cast is red herring. Although it looks uncanny, it is the same thing. The segfault is due to `dlclose` only.

Comment: Very helpful information about RAII method.